# Trigonometric form of $1+z/n $

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the trick on this problem ? I want to use that $1 + e^{ix} = 2 e^{i x/2} \cos(x/2) $ but it remains $r/n$ and I don't know what to do with this..

Thanks !

Comment: What is $r$? What is $n$?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I want to have 1 + z/n = r*e^(i blablabla), n is a positive integer

Comment: I can't imagine $1 + z/n$ having any nice polar coordinate (trigonometric) form in terms of $z, n$. If $z$ is arbitrary and $n$ is fixed, then $1 + z/n$ is arbitrary. If you take $n = 1$ for simplicity, and $z = a + bi$, then you can find a formula but it's probably not what you want. (You'll just have a formula for the modulus $r$ in terms of $a, b$ and a formula for the argument $\theta$ using $\text{atan2}$ or something.)